# PIXI.JS requestAnimationFrame doesn't reach 60fps on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, canvas, requestanimationframe, pixi.js

I'm currently building a canvas base game using [PIXI](http://www.pixijs.com/). There is one introduction scene showing animated car.

```
var textureCar = PIXI.Texture.fromImage( IMG_URL );
var car = new PIXI.Sprite( textureCar );
car.speed = 5;
```

Then I run the animation by doing:

```
requestAnimationFrame( drawStage );

function drawStage() {
    requestAnimationFrame( drawStage );

    car.position.x += car.speed;
}
```

The animation run smoothly in both Chrome and Safari on Mac, but it was really slow on iPad ios. Is there something that I miss?

Comment: Very few things reach 60 fps on Safari/iOs... (it has problems making drawImage efficient, especially when clipping is involved).

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg, do you have any references that elaborately explain the iOS drawImage and clipping issue?